# 1998 Honda Civic DX -- P1337 crankshaft position sensor 02 no signal

Tags: honda, civic

I've been doing some research, but still need a bit clarity.
As far as I know, the car has two crankshaft sensors - position sensor (CKP) and fluctuation sensor (CKF). The first one is embedded in distributor (and I guess it's the one I have the CEL error code with) and the second is quite deep under the hood and hard to reach to lol.
Common issue with CKF is that when it's not secured properly it will be rubbing on the belt it is near to and over time it's harness will tore completely. In my car it is (half way) the issue. As far as I could see the harness is pretty cut.
So my questions are,

Can the car start (and run) completely without CKF? (not doing any tricks or bypasses to it) 
Because if it cannot, then this CKF is still kind of working.

Since I have a CEL code regarding CKP, is it possible that CKF is still functioning and I have to replace the distributor? (I'll check the resistance before though)

Thank you for reading this and I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!